# multiple recipients lotusscript send

Tags: lotus-domino

On a domino-built website I have a button that runs a lotusscript agent.   Part of this agent sends emails out.  Below is summary code/snippet to give you the idea of what I am doing

(only relevant lines of code):

```
dim sendtoString as string
dim sendtoArray as variant
sendtoString = "mailaddress1,mailaddress2" '<----- two email addresses in a string
sendtoArray = split(sendtoString,|,|)
maildoc.sendto = sendtoArray
maildoc.save(true,true) '<--- so I can look at it as a saved document
'maildoc.send(false) '<----- NOTE as of right now I am not sending, choosing to simply look at the saved version until I get this right
```

The strange thing is TWO documents are SAVED.   I have not enabled the "send" line yet because I do not want multiple emails to be sent from the code, instead hoping the router will do this for me.

Maybe the send is going to work fine, and individuals will NOT receive multiple emails (if six email addresses are in the original string, I dont want six emails landing in each person's inbox).....and maybe I need to use the "SaveMessageOnSend" property instead.

Anyone have any insight on what is going on here?

Comment: Your code creates ONE document, there is no sign of creating a second doc anywhere in there. The send will only save again the same document, if SaveMessageOnSend is not set to false. The only way, this code could send two mails is, if the document was created directly in mail.box, then saving it will immediately send the mail and send will send it again...

Comment: I think the rest of the code must be relevant, especially the code that creates maildoc. I want to see what database it's created in. Is it by any chance being created directly in mail.box?

Comment: The rest of the code is indeed relevant. Can it be that the code - for some reason - is triggered twice? In which database are you creating the maildoc?

Comment: Could it be that the agent is called twice, e.g. as part of the button and as WbeQuerySave? Did you enable some sort of logging, so you can see what is executed and when?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's attempts to help, and I am at a bit of a loss as to how to respond, due to three main reasons:
1.) I am not authorized to share actual code with anyone, and so that is why I summarized it so it is kinda 'pseudo-code' and
2.) the code is not all in one place (some agent, some library), etc, and
3.) there is a lot of extraneous code for extensive logging cluttering it up

more...

Comment: What I can do is assure you that the maildoc is created inside the application itself, such as :
Dim s as new NotesSession
Dim db as Notesdatabase
Set db = s.currentdatabase
Dim maildoc as NotesDocument
Set maildoc = db.createdocument

and one more...

Comment: ...and whenever there is only a single email address in the string you saw (that is actually pulled from a configuration document associated with the current documents current status/scenario).....only one email is generated, so that I believe that rules out that this is somehow being triggered twice, unless I am missing some loop of items in the array, which I don't think is there.

However, I will keep looking

Answer (score 1):

Using LotusScript, you can generate and send email messages. When creating the email message, recipient email addresses must be assigned to the SendTo field. To send an email to a single recipient, simply set the object value to a valid email address. For example:

doc.SendTo = "someone@ibm.com"
However, when sending email to multiple recipients, you must create an array of values and append the values to the SendTo, CopyTo, or BlindCopyTo field(s). This can be achieved by building either a static or dynamic array of values.

For a full answer you can find on this blog: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.348.1/sending_email_to_multiple_recipients_using_lotusscript.html